# Java 8 Stream and filter is not working on list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In below code, I need to filter list based on 1 property called as 'CaseExternalStatusL1'. As I don't want to write needless code so I am trying to use Java 8 stream and filter with Lambda expression. When I am trying to run code all the list (inProgress,completed,pending) are still showing their size as 0 where as I am explicitly setting each object for each list.

Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
 public void saveProgressSheet(List<ProgressSheet> progressList) throws BusinessException
    {
    List<ProgressSheet> inProgress = new ArrayList<ProgressSheet>();
            List<ProgressSheet> completed = new ArrayList<ProgressSheet>();
            List<ProgressSheet> pending = new ArrayList<ProgressSheet>();
            List<EmpInitiated> empInitiatedList = new ArrayList<EmpInitiated>();
            completed=progressList.stream()
                        .filter(p -> progressList.contains(p.getCaseExternalStatusL1().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

            inProgress =progressList.stream()
                    .filter(p -> progressList.contains(p.getCaseExternalStatusL1().equalsIgnoreCase("Work In Progress")))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            pending =progressList.stream()
                    .filter(p -> progressList.contains(p.getCaseExternalStatusL1().equalsIgnoreCase("final report sent case open")))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: got it guyz.. Thanks all for your help. it worked I tried Nikita answer below. All can you please upvote for the question.

Comment: I don't understand why somebody has downvote it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mistake in predicate body. It should be.

`completed=progressList.stream().filter(p -> p.getCaseExternalStatusL1().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

since otherwise you just search for Boolean in List. Other places should be changed too.

Answer (score 1):

To take just your first filter:

```
.filter(p -> progressList.contains(p.getCaseExternalStatusL1().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")))
```

In this, you have

```
p.getCaseExternalStatusL1().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")
```

which is a boolean, and you are checking if `progressList` contains that boolean. As it is a list of `ProgressSheet`, it is not going to contain a boolean. Your predicate does not make sense.

Possibly you mean:

```
.filter(p -> p.getCaseExternalStatusL1().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed"))
```

which means "include only values `p` where

```
p.getCaseExternalStatusL1().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")
```

is true"

Comment: Yes, I mean include only value of p when value of p.getCaseExternalStatusL1().equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")